# Callback on owl carousel AFTER fully drawn on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

Imagine you have a single item carousel that sits at the absolute top of the page. Under that, you have the rest of your content. As the carousel is nested arbitrarily deep in the page, you've set it up to be absolutely positioned. But now you need to know how high the carousel is so you can put a top margin on the rest of the content so it does not overlap. This is what I am doing.

```
$('#carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  onInitialized: adjustStretchHeader,
  onResized: adjustStretchHeader
});

function adjustStretchHeader () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    return $('.page > .container')
      .css('margin-top', $('.page > .stretch-header')
        .height() + 15);
  }, 250);
}
```

On the initialisation of the carousel and on resize events, I am getting it to get the carousel's height and update the top margin. The problem is that, without having a delay, the `initialized` event is triggering before the carousel is fully drawn on the page, so the height is unreliable.

With a delay, I'm able to get it properly. But this is obviously a hack, and I cannot guarantee that on slower devices, the carousel will have been drawn in time.

I cannot see any other useful events in the [documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html).

[Demonstration fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/defayeke/xfsg53x8/)

Comment: You should provide as snippet to demonstrate this behaviour

Comment: Why not remove the `onInitialized` event and rely on the `onResized` event?

Comment: Try it for yourself. On page load resized should not be triggered so you need to trigger it for first initialisation as well

Comment: Using the `onRefreshed` event: https://jsfiddle.net/xfsg53x8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to grab the height of the images (even when they're hidden). This is independent of owlCarousel so don't have to wait for it to finish loading!

```
var images = $('#carousel img');
var firstImgHeight = images.get(0).height;
$('.page > .container').css('margin-top', firstImgHeight + 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the docs and the demos, I found this page: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/events.html

It shows that the `onRefreshed` event is called after `onInitialized` and after the images have loaded. You can use that.

```
$('#carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  onRefreshed: adjustStretchHeader
});

function adjustStretchHeader () {
    return $('.page > .container')
      .css('margin-top', $('.page > .stretch-header')
        .height() + 15);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfsg53x8/2/)

Although, I agree that the Docs aren't great at explaining the flow of the events. This still feels like a hack to me.

Comment: Testing it now actually doesn't seem to solve the problem either. I still require a delay, but this at least allows me to drop using two callbacks. Will get back to you tomorrow

Comment: @Jonathan it works in the Fiddle. Can you update your question with a working example? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not easy to reproduce exactly because it depends on the whole page loading. The example is very lightweight page.

Answer (score 0):

After initialization of carousel, DOMs of images have width but they don't have height until images are actually loaded. Try to use (width)*(aspect ratio) instead of height.

```
function adjustStretchHeader() {
  return $('.page > .container')
    .css('margin-top', $('.page > .stretch-header')
      .width() * aspectratio + 15);
}
```